# What is the earliest ADM (ADOM) templates version with the 'ByPass' option for the PowerShell 'Execution Policy?

Tags: powershell, templates, active-directory

Our client's Active Directory domain still only has 2008 templates while running servers all the way up to Windows 2022 (DCs at 2016)[image]

These are the only OPTIONS available in 2008 templates (no 'ByPass' there):
[image]

..but we need 'Bypass"

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass
```

What is the earliest ADM (ADOM) templates version with the 'ByPass' option for the PowerShell 'Execution Policy? If they apply the 2022 ADM templates is that back compatible to Windows 2012R2? I think 2016 should be good enough for now, until all the 2012R2 are rotated out; what do you all think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No support for Bypass directly in the ADMX other than to edit the registry
Using GPO Preferences>Windows Settings>Registry
Add/Edit an REG_SZ entry to the registry in the GPO of **Bypass**
HKLM>Software>Microsoft>PowerShell>1>ShellIds>Microsoft.PowerShell>Executionpolicy

[image]

[image]

Comment: Interesting, because when we set to ByPass the Group Policy refresh sets it back to RemoteSigned. so the only options from Microsoft is Restricted, RemoteSigned and Unrestricted? NO OTHER templates out there?

Comment: I suspect if you have Execution policy set as RemotedSigned in the ADMX then it will take precedence over Preferences in the GPO. Check to see that you don't have it set in the Adminstrative Templates portion of the policy. If so unset it and try again. Note also the setting exists both on the Computer side AND the User side of the GPO although it does not appear so in your screenshot. Also multiple policies can be in play here so be sure of the policy that is affecting change on the host.

Comment: CurrentUser, LocalMachine,MachinePolicy,Prcoess and UserPolicy can all be set...

Comment: So we set both the 3264 and the 64 bit PowerShell version computer object ByPass and it seems to have worked fine (once we clicked "Enforce") for the scopes MachinePolicy and LocalMachine. I was trying to figure out where the PowerShell ByPass for the "process" scope is set from... would you know?

Comment: %SystemRoot%\syswow64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe ExecutionPolicy did *not* get changed for "LocalMachine" but did get updated to ByPass for MachinePolicy, even though we applied the policy in both keys paths. 
Will MachinePolicy override LocalMachine scope's ExecutionPolicy?
                                                                                                           
PS D:\batch> gpupdate /force /target:computer
Updating policy... :
LocalMachine: RemoteSigned; MachinePolicy: Bypass

Comment: If I understand you correctly, Yes the GPO should override local machine policy since it is applied last. Perhaps test it by running a downloaded script  from PowerShell Gallery. If it unsigned, with bypass, you should not see a Consent prompt